# Will Korech move to the end of the Seder in the future?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, rashi, korban, maseches-pesachim

When we start bringing and consuming the [*Korban Pesach*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_sacrifice) again (speedily may it be, in our days), will the [*Korech*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_Seder#Koreich_.28sandwich.29) step of the [*Seder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_Sede) be moved to adjacent to [*Tzafun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_Seder#Tzafun_.28eating_of_the_afikoman.29) or possibly replaced by it?

> *Kadesh Urechatz Karpas Yachatz Magid Rochtza Motzi-Matza Maror **Korech** Shulchan-Orech Tzafun Barech Hallel Nirtza*

or

> *Kadesh Urechatz Karpas Yachatz Magid Rochtza Motzi-Matza Maror Shulchan-Orech Tzafun **Korech** Barech Hallel Nirtza*

or

> *Kadesh Urechatz Karpas Yachatz Magid Rochtza Motzi-Matza Maror Shulchan-Orech **Korech**  Tzafun Barech Hallel Nirtza*

or

> *Kadesh Urechatz Karpas Yachatz Magid Rochtza Motzi-Matza Maror Shulchan-Orech Tzafun(=**Korech**) Barech Hallel Nirtza*

The reason for *Korech* is that there was a disagreement between Hillel and his contemporaries, recorded in [*Talmud Bavli Pesachim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesachim_%28Talmud%29) [115a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=115&format=pdf) ([English summary](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/pesachim/points/ps-ps-115.htm)), regarding whether to eat the [*Korban Pesach*,] matza, and [*maror*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maror) together in one wrap (Hillel) or separately (contemporaries). I put "*Korban Pesach*] in brackets in the previous sentence because whether the *Korban Pesach* was part of Hillel's wrap is the subject of a [later disagreement](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/ZecherLemikdashKehillel.htm) between [Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) and [Rashbam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashbam) there, who hold that it was, and [Rambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) in [*Hilchot Chametz Umataza* 8:6-8](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Leavened_and_Unleavened_Bread.8.6-8?lang=he-en), who implies that the wrap was only matza and *maror*, while the *Korban Pesach* was eaten separately.

*Tzafun* is a placeholder for eating of the *Korban Pesach*, which, as encoded in [*Mishna Pesachim* 10:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.10.8?lang=he-en), must be the last food consumed on Pesach night.

Therefore, when we restore the practice of *Korban Pesach*, we will presumably eat it in the *Tzafun* slot in the *Seder*. If we follow the Rambam's interpretation of Hillel's practice, then that plus the *Korech* we're already used to, on the schedule we're used to, fulfills both Hillel's opinion and that of his contemporaries, since they agreed that the *Korban Pesach* was eaten by itself, at the end of the meal. However, according to Rashi and Rashbam, fulfilling Hillel's opinion would presumably require making a wrap including the *Korban Pesach*, presumably at the end of the meal.

1. According to Rashi and Rashbam, would *Korech* have to be at the end of the meal?
2. Would it be before, after, or in place of eating the *Korban Pesach* by itself (*Tzafun*)?
3. Is it possible that we will, in fact, practice in accordance with Rashi and Rashbam? Does the current placement of *Korech* where it is instead of at the end of the meal already indicate that we don't?

Comment: No one will be eating maror alone then, presumably.

Comment: re 3: There is a different good reason to have it earlier nowadays which relates to having the brachot on matza and maror cover korech as well. So I don't think our current practice is a proof.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why do you presume that no one will be eating Maror alone? Will we revert to only practicing in accordance with Hillel? ... Or when it's all de-oraita, does that become according to everyone?

Comment: Note Korban Pesach could also be eaten in the beginning. It just had to also be the last thing. See rambam :7 and :9 that you cited.

Comment: Maror nowadays is rabbinic zecher lemikdash. In the future we'll just do it 'with the korban pesach' (whatever that means) like we're supposed to. See tosfot (?) there about deoraitas and derabanans with the issue of mitzvot mevatlot zo et zo. (I may be misapplying something as this is from memory, but I think that's the idea)

Comment: @DoubleAA I hadn't seen #9. Maybe that answers my question: We'd incorporate the Pesach into pre-meal phases, including Korech, and retain the Tzafun as meat by itself just to make it the last thing.

Comment: You seem more in the sugya than me so don't worry about using my suggestions in writing a good answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've never sat down and learned this sugya, including the whole derabana/deoraita business, carefully. I just got as much as I thought I needed to pose this question intelligently.

Comment: You left out the possibility that we interpret the medrash literally about l'asid lavo all the moadim are batel except purim and yom kippur and that that might mean no more pesachim.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're asking with the assumption that we rule like _Hilel_.

Comment: @msh210 my assumption is that we currently take both Hillel and his contemporaries into account, and that we will continue to so so when we bring the korban. Challenges to either assumption are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be a dispute between Rashi and Rambam, but partly for a different reason. Before we factor in the dispute between Hillel and the Sages (and *rishonim*'s interpretations thereof) we need to define what the essential nature of *tzafun* is. This appears to be a dispute between Rashi and Rambam. As I noted in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91206/13438) the simple reading of Rambam is that the *tzafun* step is not really part of the *mitzvah*. The essential *mitzvot* of *matzah*, *maror* and *korban pesach* are fulfilled by eating those three things prior to the main meal, as Rambam codifies in [8:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2288) and [8:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2289). Once you've done that you have fulfilled all three mitzvot. There is a separate rabbinic institution that we should eat the *korban pesach* again after the meal in order for it to be the last taste in our mouths, as Rambam explains in [6:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2268).

Now if the purpose of *tzafun*was just to make the *korban pesach* be the last taste in your mouth, it would presumably be irrelevant how the *mitzvah* of *korban pesach* must be fulfilled. It doesn't matter what Hillel holds, what the Sages hold, or how *rishonim* interpret that dispute, because that was all already taken care of before the meal when we ate all three items and tried to fulfill both opinions. After the meal we are not attempting to fulfill the *mitzvah*; we are simply leaving the taste of the *korban pesach* in our mouths, which should not require any accompaniment of *matzah* or *maror*.

However, Rashi on [Pesachim 119b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=119b&format=pdf) seems to explain the point of *tzafun* differently. He seems to assume that the main *mitzvah* is actually fulfilled by what is eaten during *tzafun*. If so, then we would presumably fall under the dispute between Hillel and the Sages as to how to correctly do the *mitzvah*. Thus, according to Rashi's explanation of Hillel on [115a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=115&format=pdf), you would presumably have to wrap all three together for *tzafun* as that is how you would fulfill the *mitzvah* in Hillel's view.

If you mix and match opinions and follow Rashi's interpretation of the nature of *tzafun* but Rambam's interpretation of Hillel's view then you would presumably have to eat a wrap of *matzah* and *maror* after the meal when you eat the *korban pesach*.

Here is a chart:

[image: A chart showing the breakdown of the different opinions]